# "He feels more than he is" is correct to say that someone thinks he is better than he actually is?

Tags: phrase-requests

"He feels more than he is" is correct  to say that someone thinks he is better than he actually is? 
I don't know if that is correct, if it is not, which other short way to say it could work?

Comment: No, it isn't. ..........

Comment: Does it need to be multiple words? What about words like overconfident, conceited, or cocksure?

Comment: A common, modern way to express this, with a whole sentence (at least in the U.S.) is "He thinks he's all that."  In the 60s I used to hear, "He thinks he's so great."  You can also look in the thesaurus under "arrogant" "conceited" and "egotistical."

Comment: To the person who voted to close (proofreading): this is not a proofreading question.  It's a plain old vocabulary question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep as close to your original phrase as possible, instead try 'he feels he is more than he is'. I realize this is a bit awkward, so perhaps editing it to some extent would be helpful. Or using a different phrase, like 'his ego is large' or 'his head is big'.
If you want a more colorful turn of phrase, try 'he thinks his shit doesn't stink'.